# An ajax http request terminated abnormally with debug info

Tags: forms, ajax, files

I received the following error while adding image in my blog post:

```
Location: http://www.mysite.com/file/ajax/field_screenshot/und/0/
form-YKEwrcYmmrIxDcswqmKmGPwZwYZDtkhPmp_C9v49L94
Referrer: http://www.mysite.com/node/5536/edit

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'public://images/davidwachira/algebraic_equation_in_c.png' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri, 
filemime, filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
:db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 27454 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => algebraic_equation_in_c.png [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 
public://images/davidwachira/algebraic_equation_in_c.png [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => image/png [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 
25601 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1375233694 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7136 of 
/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/common.inc).
```

I have already tested all browsers and it returns the same error.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

BTW, I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: uri column in file_manage table has a unique constrain
so did you try to rename this file and check again

Comment: I deleted the duplicate and issue this sql `SELECT uri, COUNT( * ) 
FROM file_managed
GROUP BY uri
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1;` and I found no duplicate. But still the same error.

Comment: I restarted MySQL and memcached and this time the error has gone but there is no thumbnail and medium image size created as what I have defined in `Image styles`.